# Where to create a web-site map for developers

Tags: html, documentation

Imagine a web-designer built several mock-up html pages. Now it is time to start development according to these mock-ups.

First of all I would like to know that all mock-ups are there, i.e. every link has corresponded mock-up page. I can't just click hyperlinks, because they are empty ('#' url).

And secondly, I would like to have kind of map, where developer can look at and figure out transitions from the page and hence fill it with appropriate urls.

Does any body know any tools that can help to make such documents which reflect my needs stated above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[MS Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) for Windows or [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/) for OSX can help you build a scenario project where you can design an interactive diagram where each box represents a page. When you click a box it shows the page mockup associated with this box. You can also draw lines between each box that represents links to other pages from this page.

Answer (score 1):

- [balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) a flex app
- [Axure](http://www.axure.com/) windows desktop app
- Expression blend 3 from Microsoft has [Sketchflow](http://blogs.msdn.com/somasegar/archive/2009/04/25/prototyping-with-sketchflow.aspx).